# How to start the stopped ubuntu container in docker? (ran without options (-i - t) )

Tags: docker

How to start the stopped ubuntu container in docker? any idea?

**$docker pull ubuntu**

**$docker images**

REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE

ubuntu              latest              7698f282e524        29 hours ago        69.9MB

**$docker run ubuntu**

**$docker ps -a**

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES

512009f5b00e        ubuntu              "/bin/bash"         39 minutes ago      Exited (0) About a minute ago                       sad_noether

**$docker start sad_noether**

sad_noether

**$docker ps**

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

**$docker ps -a**

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES

512009f5b00e        ubuntu              "/bin/bash"         40 minutes ago      Exited (0) 23 seconds ago                       sad_noether

**$docker exec -it sad_noether bash**

Error response from daemon: Container 512009f5b00e6be5e3ee199d2db25c628219c237b16e37eed5cb6052179ebdbc is not running

Comment: Where does `sad_noether` come from?

Comment: edited the question, unable to start the ubuntu container after exited.

Comment: Why not `docker start sad_noether` again?

Comment: I tried, but it exits right after the start, unable to keep the container running by attaching any commands like bash

Comment: `docker rm` the container that doesn't start, and `docker run` a new container that actually does the thing you need it to.  Since a plain Ubuntu image doesn't have any applications installed, usually you'll need to write a Dockerfile that installs software and runs some single thing as a foreground process.

Answer (score 2):

> How to start the stopped ubuntu container in docker?

```
docker start CONTAINER
```

In your case, you ran ubuntu without any foreground process, so the container exits immediately when you start it.

You should run `docker run -it ubuntu bash`

Comment: this creates new ubuntu container, not starting the stopped one

Comment: `sad_noether`  is created by `docker run ubuntu`, it will exit immediately because there's no foreground process. and if start it again by `docker start sad_noether`, it will start and exit immediately again.

Comment: so, no way to start the existing stopped container?

Comment: `docker start CONTAINER` . As for `sad_noether` , it started, but exited immediately

Comment: My findings, after $docker run -it ubuntu and exit from ubuntu container, basically exit command stops the ubuntu container. In this case possible to start the same container back using $docker start <container_id>

But, It is not working If we run without options (-it) $docker run ubuntu..

Answer (score 2):

You should run this to keep the container running.

```
docker run -d ubuntu sleep 9999999
```

Comment: question @klbjlabs, how to start the container back after docker stop <container_id>

Comment: docker container is a process-level.  when the process stop, the container stop. so must have a command keep running on the frontend. 
like 'sleep 99999' or something another command.

Answer (score 1):

1. docker run -it centos /bin/bash
   [to run the container the first time and exit.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqIM1.png)
2. docker ps -a
   [to see that container is stopped.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbVMw.png)
3. docker start -ai [CONTAINER_ID]
   [to start the existing container.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghUE2.png)
4. You are into the container!